# Get rid of underscores in filename of the file to be downloaded

Tags: alfresco, document-library

I have a file in alfresco document library containing whitespaces in its name, and I'm using IE8 which inserts underscores instead of the whitespaces when downloading the file.

Is it possible to get rid of these underscores, and have the whitespaces conserved in the filename when downloading?

Answer (score 1):

that's not an #Alfresco related questions. It's a know IE issue - e.g. take a look here:
[HttpResponse substituting underscores for spaces in file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625503/httpresponse-substituting-underscores-for-spaces-in-file-names)